# How to sort a data frame by alphabetic order of a character variable in R?

Tags: r

I would like to sort a data frame by alphabetic order of a character variable in R. I've tried to do it with the `order()` function but it transforms my data frame into a list. Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Could you post what you tried to do (code and data) ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Well, I've got no problem here :

```
df <- data.frame(v=1:5, x=sample(LETTERS[1:5],5))
df

#   v x
# 1 1 D
# 2 2 A
# 3 3 B
# 4 4 C
# 5 5 E

df <- df[order(df$x),]
df

#   v x
# 2 2 A
# 3 3 B
# 4 4 C
# 1 1 D
# 5 5 E
```

Answer (score 14):

```
#sort dataframe by col
sort.df <- with(df,  df[order(sortbythiscolumn) , ])

#can also sort by more than one variable: sort by col1 and then by col2
sort2.df <- with(df, df[order(col1, col2) , ])

#sort in reverse order
sort2.df <- with(df, df[order(col1, -col2) , ])
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite clear yet, that `col1` should be `df$col1` here. I'd be happy to up-vote if you could edit this part. And you could probably add the nice use of `with` here as well!

Comment: (+1) I'd rather use `df[with(df, order(col1, col2)),]`, but both seem to be the same underneath.

Answer (score 9):

The `arrange` function in the `plyr` package makes it easy to sort by multiple columns. For example, to sort `DF` by `ID` first and then decreasing by `num`, you can write

```
plyr::arrange(DF, ID, desc(num))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `order` function:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(ID= sample(letters[1:26], 15, TRUE),
                 num = sample(1:100, 15, TRUE),
                 random = rnorm(15),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF[order(DF[,'ID']), ]
   ID num      random
10  b  27  0.61982575
12  e   2 -0.15579551
5   f  78  0.59390132
11  f  39 -0.05612874
1   g  50 -0.04493361
2   j  72 -0.01619026
14  j  87 -0.47815006
3   o 100  0.94383621
9   q  13 -1.98935170
8   r  66  0.07456498
13  r  39 -1.47075238
15  u  35  0.41794156
4   x  39  0.82122120
6   x  94  0.91897737
7   y  22  0.78213630
```

Another solution would be using `orderBy`function from doBy package:

```
> library(doBy)
> orderBy(~ID, DF)
```

Answer (score 3):

This really belongs with @Ramnath's answer but I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation yet. You can also use the `arrange` function from the `dplyr` package in the same way as the `plyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(DF, ID, desc(num))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `order()` function fails when the column has levels or factor. It works properly when `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is used in data.frame creation.