# Sort a tibble by index in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Looking to sort a tibble by index in R. Any way to do this without using a reverse sequence?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

    options(tibble.width = Inf)
    options(dplyr.print_max = Inf)
```

Returns the tail for comparison...

```
iris %>% tail
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
# 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
# 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
# 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
# 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
# 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica

(tibbleIris <- as_tibble(iris))
```

Can sort by reverse sequence, but it's not by index...

```
tibbleIris[nrow(tibbleIris):1,] # Sorts in reverse order
# # A tibble: 150 × 5
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <fctr>
#   1            5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
# 2            6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica
# 3            6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica
# 4            6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica
# 5            6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica
# 6            6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica


tibbleIris %>% arrange(-index)
# Error: object 'index' not found
```

Comment: What do you mean by `index`?

Comment: `rownames(tibbleIris)` returns the string of index. Wondering if there's a way to sort by rowname as integer, for example.

Comment: Since `index` isn't defined in R, but you define it as `rownames(tibbleIris)`, you could try telling R your definition... something like `tibbleIris[order(rownames(tibbleIris)), ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to sort a data frame by alphabetic order of a character variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14817620/903061)

Comment: `iris[ order(as.numeric(rownames(iris)),decreasing = T), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what you mean: this seems to work:

```
iris %>% as_tibble %>% arrange(desc(as.numeric(rownames(iris))))
```

(I left out the intermediate assignment to `tibbleIris` for simplicity).  Using rownames is rather un-tidyverse-ish, so I might suggest setting up an explicit index variable instead ...

```
iris %>% as_tibble %>% mutate(index=seq(n())) %>% 
      arrange(desc(index))
```

Comment: good question [now deleted: "is there a reference that defines un-tidyverse-ishness?"]  Presumably Wickham's books.  I gathered this particular idea from the fact that tibbles don't allow rownames to be set, e.g. https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/114

Comment: Thanks...I popped tidyverse into google (as I should have before asking), and pulled up R for Data Science. It seems like that would be a safe bet. P.S. "un-tidyverse-ishness" is certainly untidy

Comment: There's the tidyverse and then there's base R (upon which the tidyverse rests, of course), both of which are useful in different situations. For instance, there probably is a way to label thousands of variables from metadata without knowing their names to begin with using tidyverse commands, but if so, I haven't found it. It's trivial using base r, though.